# The column 'value' was specified multiple times en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

estoy intentando hacer una consulta en SQL Server en dónde necesito separar los valores por **guion medio (-)** de dos de mis campos (**emplAddress** y **emplPhone**), la tabla original es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder dividir la cadena por **guion medio** y en una columna estoy haciendo uso de la función **STRING_SPLIT()** cabe mencionar que para almacenar los valores estoy asignando un alias al resultando que me arroja la función en un value de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT emplAddress, emplPhone, 'Ads' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR) AS ColAddress,
Split.value, 'Phon' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR) AS ColPhone, 
Pho.value FROM empleados AS Emp
CROSS APPLY string_split(emplAddress, '-') AS Split
CROSS APPLY string_split(emplPhone, '-') AS Pho
```

Lo que me da cómo resultado lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error viene cuándo intento trasponer las columnas generadas con **STRING_SPLIT()** mediante **PIVOT()** me dice que la columna **value** es asignada múltiples veces pero cuando pongo algún otro nombre a una de las columnas cómo **val** o **result** no me lo permite en mi consulta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

consulta SQL con value en ambos alias:

```
SELECT emplAddress, emplPhone, ISNULL([Ads1], '') AS [Ads1], ISNULL([Ads2], '') AS [Ads2], ISNULL([Ads3], '') AS [Ads3],
 ISNULL([Ads4], '') AS [Ads4], ISNULL([Phon1], '') AS [Phon1], ISNULL([Phon2], '') AS [Phon2], ISNULL([Phon3], '') AS [Phon3]
FROM(
    SELECT emplAddress, emplPhone, 'Ads' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR) AS ColAddress,
    Split.value, 'Phon' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR) AS ColPhone, 
    Pho.value FROM empleados AS Emp
    CROSS APPLY string_split(emplAddress, '-') AS Split
    CROSS APPLY string_split(emplPhone, '-') AS Pho
) AS tblEmpleados
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR ColAddress IN ([Ads1], [Ads2], [Ads3], [Ads4])) AS pvtAddress
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR ColPhone IN ([Phon1], [Phon2], [Phon3])) AS tblEmpleadosFinal
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me podrían orientar un poco para poder solucionar este tema?.**

De ante mano agradezco su apoyo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que estás intentando hacer (al final está la explicación de mis cambios):

```
SELECT emplAddress, emplPhone, 
       MAX(ISNULL([Ads1], '')) AS [Ads1],   MAX(ISNULL([Ads2], '')) AS [Ads2],   MAX(ISNULL([Ads3], '')) AS [Ads3], MAX(ISNULL([Ads4], '')) AS [Ads4], 
       MAX(ISNULL([Phon1], '')) AS [Phon1], MAX(ISNULL([Phon2], '')) AS [Phon2], MAX(ISNULL([Phon3], '')) AS [Phon3]
FROM(
    SELECT id, emplAddress, emplPhone,Orden,
            'Ads' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, Pho_Value ORDER BY Orden) AS VARCHAR) AS ColAddress,
            Ads_Value,
            'Phon' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, Ads_Value ORDER BY Orden) AS VARCHAR) AS ColPhone,
            Pho_Value
    FROM (
        SELECT id, emplAddress, emplPhone,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS Orden,
            Split.value AS Ads_Value, 
            Pho.value AS Pho_Value 
        FROM empleados AS Emp
        CROSS APPLY string_split(emplAddress, '-') AS Split
        CROSS APPLY string_split(emplPhone, '-') AS Pho
    ) X
) AS tblEmpleados
    PIVOT (MAX(Ads_Value) FOR ColAddress IN ([Ads1], [Ads2], [Ads3], [Ads4])) AS pvtAddress
    PIVOT (MAX(Pho_Value) FOR ColPhone IN ([Phon1], [Phon2], [Phon3])) AS tblEmpleadosFinal
GROUP BY id, emplAddress, emplPhone
ORDER BY id
```

Y este el resultado (lo probé con datos de ejemplo parecidos a los tuyos):

[image: Tabla de resultados]

**Cambios en la consulta:**

1. Primero que nada, probé el código en SQL Server 2014, pero como no tengo al función `string_split`, tuve que "reemplazarla" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505547/1858280), aunque debe funcionar igual.
2. El error que te sale no es por los dos "value" que están en el pivot, sino por los dos "value" que están en la subconsulta: `Split.value` y `Pho.value`. En el nuevo código les puse los alias `Ads_Value` y `Pho_Value` respectivamente (también en los Pivot del final).
3. Eso resuelve el error, pero las columnas `ColAddress` y `ColPhone` quedaban mal enumeradas: para cada ID, todas las partes de las direcciones con el mismo valor deberían tener el mismo AdsX ("San Miguel" = Ads1, "XOCHIQUETZAL" = Ads2, etc). Lo mismo debe pasar con los teléfonos. Para solucionar esto, agregué la columna `Orden` en la subconsulta, y moví las columnas `ColAddress` y `ColPhone` a una subconsulta superior. En esta nueva subconsulta superior puedes ver que los Row_Number ahora particionan tanto por ID como por el valor de la columna *contraria* (las direcciones por Pho_Value, y los teléfonos por Ads_Value), y se ordena por el nuevo campo Orden.
4. Lo último que hice fue agregar un GROUP BY al final (y MAX para las 8 columnas nuevas), para eliminar los duplicados.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, tengo una duda más no sé si me puedas ayudar a aclarar, continuando con la práctica me entró la curiosidad de agregar un nuevo campo a mi tabla con un valor numérico (simulando el salario de la persona) pero al momento de agregarlo a la subconsulta me pide que agregue una función de agregado, entonces agrego la función SUM(emplSalary) AS emplSalary y después de eso me tira el mismo error el resto de los campos. ¿Cómo podría solucionar ese tema para que me aparezca el resultado que me mostraste pero agregando el salario del empleado?

Comment: Sobre el salario: si el campo está en la tabla `empleados` entonces el campo debes incluirlo en el SELECT de la subconsulta más interna, luego en el de la subconsulta siguiente, y finalmente en la consulta superior. Pero el `SUM(Salario) AS Salario` debes colocarlo solo en la consulta superior, que es la que lleva el GROUP BY. En las internas no hace falta el MAX porque no tienen agrupación.